# GWT Templates & GXT Xtemplates - how to sanitize display fields

Tags: gwt, gxt

I'm just getting into using @Template and @XTemmplate within my code.
I'm always concerned about user originated content vs trusted content.

This is the sample from GWT [SafeHtml](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml?hl=de#SafeHtmlTemplates)

```
 public interface MyTemplates extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<span class=\"{3}\">{0}: <a href=\"{1}\">{2}</a></span>")
    SafeHtml messageWithLink(SafeHtml message, String url, String linkText,
        String style);
  }
```

This is the sample from the GXT [XTemplate doc](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3/com/sencha/gxt/core/client/XTemplates.html)

```
public interface SampleXTemplates extends XTemplates {
  @XTemplate("<div>Hello, {name}!</div>")
  SafeHtml hello(String name);
}
```

In either, is there a way in the template to declare a display field to be sanitized or trusted?
Something ala [HtmlSanitizer](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/HtmlSanitizer.html)

Answer (score 1):

All `String` values rendered in an XTemplate/SafeHtmlTemplates are automatically sanitized - try passing in `<`, `>`, or `&` characters. This is true whether they are passed in to an attribute or the space between tags. If GWT cannot enure the safety of such a string (such as passing it into the `href` attribute of the `a` tag, or into a `style` attribute), it will emit a warning. Your first example is likely to get such a warning.

`SafeHtml` instances can be passed in to declare 'I know that this string is safe'. Typically, you create those using `SafeHtmlUtils`, a `SafeHtmlBuilder` instance, or another template of some kind.

Safe urls can be `SafeUri` instances - create them with `UriUtils`. This will get around the possible warning in your first example.

Safe styles can be `SafeStyles` instances - create them using `SafeStylesBuilder` instances or static methods in the `SafeStylesUtils` class.

And finally, as an implementation detail, XTemplates are generated by parsing out the logic and the named parameters and getters, and turned into SafeHtmlTemplates before generated into JavaScript. This ensures that anything that SafeHtmlTemplates will make safe will also be safe in XTemplates.